# Collapsing duplicate row entries and count them?

Tags: vba, duplicates

I think what I'm trying to do is pretty basic, but I'm brand new to VBA so I'm getting stuck and the answers I've found are close, but not quite right.

I have a list of row entries, like this:

```
1 4 32 2 4
2 6 33 1 3 
1 4 32 2 4
4 2 30 1 5
```

Notice that rows 1 and 3 are duplicates. I'd like to only have a single instance of each unique row but I don't want to just delete the duplicates, I want to report how many of each type there are. Each row represents an inventory item, so deleting duplicate entries without indicating total quantity would be very bad!

So, my desired output would look something like this, where the additional 6th column counts the total number of instances of each item:

```
1 4 32 2 4 2
2 6 33 1 3 1
4 2 30 1 5 1
```

My data sets are larger than just these 5 columns, they're closer to 10 or so, so I'd like to put that last column at the end, rather than to hardcode it to the 6th column (i.e., column "F")

Update:

I found some code that worked with minor tweaking, and it worked this morning, but after messing around with some other macros, when I came back to this one it was telling me that I have a "compile error, wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment" and it seemed to be unhappy with the "range". Why would working code stop working?

```
Sub mcrCombineAndScrubDups2()
    For Each a In range("A1", Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
        For r = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row - a.Row
            If a = a.Offset(r, 0) And a.Offset(0, 1) = a.Offset(r, 1) And a.Offset(0, 2) = a.Offset(r, 2) Then
                a.Offset(0, 4) = a.Offset(0, 4) + a.Offset(r, 4)
                a.Offset(r, 0).EntireRow.Delete
                r = r - 1
            End If
        Next r
    Next a
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your data starts from `A1` on a worksheet named `ws1`, the following code removes the duplicated rows. Not by shifting the whole table but deleting the entire row.

```
Sub deletedupe() 
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim row1 As String
    Dim row2 As String

    i = 1
    j = 1
    k = 1
    Do While Sheets("ws1").Cells(i, 1).Value <> ""
        row1 = ""
        j = 1
        Do While Sheets("ws1").Cells(i, j).Value <> ""
            row1 = row1 & Sheets("ws1").Cells(i, j).Value & " "
            j = j + 1
        Loop
        k = i + 1
        Do While Sheets("ws1").Cells(k, 1).Value <> ""
            row2 = ""
            j = 1
            Do While Sheets("ws1").Cells(k, j).Value <> ""
                row2 = row2 & Sheets("ws1").Cells(k, j).Value & " "
                j = j + 1
            Loop
            If row1 = row2 Then
                Sheets("ws1").Rows(k).EntireRow.Delete
            Else
                k = k + 1
            End If
        Loop
        i = i + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```